# Trying to illustrate Perfect Forwarding with pairs

Tags: c++, std-pair, perfect-forwarding

I think I understood perfect forwarding and took a code that normaly illustrate it

```
template<typename T, typename U>
std::pair<T, U> make_pair_wrapper(T&& t, U&& u)
{
    return std::make_pair(std::forward<T>(t),
                          std::forward<U>(u));
}

int main()
{
    std::pair<std::string, int> p1 = make_pair_wrapper("foo", 42);
}
```

But i doesn't compile, saying that it can't convert from `'std::pair<const char*, int>'` to `'std::pair<const char (&)[4], int>`

I have to admit that I don't understand

Comment: `T` and `U` are deduced to `std::string&` and `int&` respectively, which you are using as the types for your returned pair (`pair<T,U>==pair<string&,int&>`). However, `std::make_pair()` decays the return pair types so that the arguments can be copy/moved into the new pair. So the return type and type of the return expression are incompatible, and so is the type of `p1` with its initializer. All that's needed is to strip the references of `T` and `U` from the the return type of `make_pair_wrapper`, or deduce them automatically with `auto`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass variables instead of temporaries.
This line is incorrect

```
pair<string, int> p1 = make_pair_wrapper("foo",42);
```

Pair stores `std::string` and `int`, but you pass to function `const char*` and `int`. `const char*` is not `std::string`.
You could do:

<s>make_pair_wrapper(s, i);</s>

or:

```
make_pair_wrapper(std::string("foo"), 42);
```

You must work with temporaries, that can't be omitted. But if you really want to have a "variable" feel, then you can extend life of temporaries:

```
const int& i = 42;
const string& s = "foo";
```

Then, you can pass them to the function (but I don't recommend that).

Comment: I edited and tried, but it also doesn't compile. To be complete, it works with  make_pair_wrapper(std::string("foo"), 42); but not with make_pair_wrapper(s, i);

Comment: Also, perfect forwarding shouldn't work with temporaries too ?

Comment: `s` and `i` aren't temporaries. If you want to make this work, you need to `std::forward` them in the function call.

Answer (score 1):

Your return type is not equivalent to the one of `std::make_pair`, thus the error. Declaration of `make_pair` is:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
constexpr std::pair<std::decay_t<T1>, std::decay_t<T2>>
make_pair(T1&& t, T2&& u)
```

You have to use correct type, the more generic is `decltype(auto)`

```
template<typename T, typename U>
decltype(auto)
make_pair_wrapper(T&& t, U&& u)
{
    return std::make_pair(std::forward<T>(t),
                          std::forward<U>(u));
}
```

A simple `auto` can be used in that case (as `make_pair` return by value).
`decltype(auto)` would be required if the function returns reference.

A more verbose way would be to use

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto
make_pair_wrapper(T&& t, U&& u)
-> decltype(std::make_pair(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<U>(u)));
```

The last one allows the forwarding of SFINAE.

Comment: In this case `auto` as a return type is enough. Am I wrong?

Comment: Is it required to use `decltype(auto)`? `auto` isn't enough in this case?

Comment: @ skypjack: `auto` is enough in that case, as the return type is by value indeed.

Comment: @BlackMoses: `decltype(auto)` is more generic, even if `auto` is enough in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Your `make_pair` call is incompatible with the `pair<T1,T2>` type.

A solution is

```
template<typename T, typename U>
std::pair<T, U> make_pair_wrapper(T&& t, U&& u)
{
    return {std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<U>(u)};
}
```